# "Merging" bags of same size in Pig Latin

Tags: join, merge, apache-pig, bag

Is there any way to "merge" two bags of the same size in Pig?

For example: I have two bags like this -

```
({(0.05,0.0),(0.05,0.0)}, {a, b})
```

and all I want is:

```
(0.05,0.0,a), (0.05,0.0,b)
```

(Doesn't matter if it is in bags or tuples).

This seems super straightforward to go the UDF way. Is there a simple solution using Pig operators or DataFu UDFs?

Comment: Does order matter at all for this?

Answer (score 0):

If order does not matter then you can do this using an [UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/udf.html).  In Python:

```
@outputSchema('combined:{(f1, f2, f3)}')
def combine_equal_bags(bag1, bag2):
    out = []
    for b1, b2 in zip(bag1, bag2):
        out.append(b1 + (b2,))
    return out
```

This is not possible using just pure-Pig.